# How many rolls for POW Murderous Insight and critical hits?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, critical-hit, path-of-war

The [stalker](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/classes/stalker/) has the following ability

> Murderous Insight (Su): The stalker designates his combat senses towards ending the lives of his opponents and gains momentary flashes of insight in how to best accomplish this. The stalker can activate this ability by spending one point of ki as a swift action; for a number of rounds equal to 1 + his stalker initiation modifier, he can roll twice on a single attack roll each round and take the higher value.

[Critical Hits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Critical-Hits)

> To find out if it’s a critical hit, you immediately make an attempt to “confirm” the critical hit—another attack roll with all the same modifiers as the attack roll you just made.

So would you be allowed to roll twice during the confirm part or roll once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Strict RAW

If you do not use your roll twice ability before the critical threat, then **you could use it on the confirmation roll**. Using the ability and receiving a critical threat *does not* provide the roll twice ability to the confirmation roll.

### As always, ask your GM...

A confirmation roll is an Attack Roll... but not all GM's will consider it an *attack roll* as the ability considers it. One might think the intent was for it to be making the attack or that critical confirms are more of a check than an attack. You should consult your GM with the evidence that you *should* be able to use it to confirm and see if they agree, before trying to use it as such in play.